# Service has reported an invalid current state 0 - Looking for an explanation as to "why this is only happening now"

Tags: vb.net, winapi, service

On this occasion I'm not really looking for an answer but rather, an explanation.

We have developed a number of Windows Services in VB.NET, and those services have been working fine on many of our customer sites. In all these services we defined a Service Status Structure as follows:

```
    <Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure ServiceStatus
    Public dwServiceType As Long
    Public dwCurrentState As ServiceState
    Public dwControlsAccepted As Long
    Public dwWin32ExitCode As Long
    Public dwServiceSpecificExitCode As Long
    Public dwCheckPoint As Long
    Public dwWaitHint As Long
End Structure
```

And in the last few days, in ONE customer site, for ONE of these services, in the Event Viewer it logged the error: **Service has reported an invalid current state 0**

I searched for this and soon found the following suggested solution:

```
    <Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)>
Public Structure ServiceStatus
    Public dwServiceType As UInteger
    Public dwCurrentState As ServiceState
    Public dwControlsAccepted As UInteger
    Public dwWin32ExitCode As UInteger
    Public dwServiceSpecificExitCode As UInteger
    Public dwCheckPoint As UInteger
    Public dwWaitHint As UInteger
End Structure
```

I'm optimistic that that will solve our problem, but what bothers me is how these services have always **appeared** to work just fine. If someone would be so kind as to explain how it might be possible that we dodged this bullet for so long, I would very much appreciate it.

If this really isn't the right place to ask a question like this, just tell me and I'll be happy to delete it.

Comment: The bug is probably in the code that subsequently calls [`SetServiceStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-setservicestatus), caused by sign-extension as part of integer promotion from some integer type to `Long`.

Comment: Thanks ... I just find it astonishing that this, mistakes and all, has worked without any problems for so many people for such a long time.

Comment: `ServiceState` isn't defined.

Comment: The following may be helpful in your quest for knowledge: [SERVICE_STATUS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/ns-winsvc-service_status), [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN), [Data Type Summary (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/).

Comment: [LayoutKind Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.layoutkind?view=netframework-4.8), [StructLayoutAttribute.Pack Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack?view=netframework-4.8), [IntPtr.Size Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr.size?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thank you very much... All very helpful indeed. My main concern, however, is how is it possible that we "got away with it" for so long? We wrote four Services with the incorrectly defined Structure in it, and all four had been working "fine" (or at least, never raised any errors) on various machines for years. Only last week, on one machine in one of our clients did this raise the error as described in the title, and even there that only happened after it had been running fine on the same machine before. Tis a mystery to confound :-)

Comment: Hi @Lundt - my apologies, ServiceState was defined in other parts of the code as a Public Enum, and in my corrected code I defined it as a Public Enum ... As UInteger

Comment: And I forgot to mention.... I corrected the structure yesterday and the service is once again starting successfully. Which, I guess, it should now that the problem has been addressed, but my mind boggles as to why we never came up against this before ...